# Why is QGIS too slow to load a project?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, windows

I work as an IT assistant and one of the workstations from the company that I work on, takes around 10 minutes to load a project of around 70gb. It takes the same amount of time if I load the project from Google Drive through the Desktop app or if I have it locally.

The specs of this workstation are:

- Model: Dell Precision 3630 Tower
- CPU: Xeon E-2174G @3.80
- 16GB RAM
- SSD 256 GB
- W11 Pro

If I load the same project in another workstation with the same specs, except this one has another SSD, of 2 TB; then, in this one the project loads in 30s.

I joined the Spanish QGIS Telegram group and one user suggested closing the browser window. In the problematic PC, QGIS keeps getting laggy.

I tried to uninstall and install QGIS multiple times and I used 3 different versions (3.28.8, 3.28.10, 3.32.2) but with the same result in the 3.

I don't know what's wrong because the amount of RAM consumed is logical : 10/16 in total, similar as with the other PCs that I tried. QGIS takes around 1GB of RAM.
Furthermore, in this PC the plugins that launch to startup take less time to load than in the other PC that I said it takes 30s to load the project. This is based on the information given by the plugin "Load Times".

Can anyone give me any other tip and tell me what are the recommended requirements to launch QGIS? I haven't found them on their official website.

Comment: what happens loading QGIS in safe mode? (aka no plugins) https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/272775/276

Comment: Look at plugins (some will load a ton of "data" from the web at each startup!) or at the layers source (ex: trying to connect to a network drive / URL that times out)

Comment: Hi, in terms of startup plugins can't be a problem because in this problematic PC plugins are loaded faster than in the other PC that I mentioned in which the project is loaded at a decent time. 
However, tomorrow I'll try to load QGIs without plugins  as @Mapperz suggests.

Comment: The browser used to make QGIS painfully slow when it looked for unreachable network drive or even by simply having the browser panel open you may want to investigate that. This (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384354/qgis-3-10-13-64-bit-on-a-asus-laptop-with-windows-10-is-running-extremely-slow/384358#384358) discuss some slowness problem (not at loading but could help)

Comment: Reduce the time until network timeout, save projects without tracing/snapping enabled, reduce amount of layers in project, maybe upgrade your connection to the server your data is saved on (both ends).

Comment: @J.R In the problematic PC even with the browser window closed it keeps loading too slow. Tomorrow I'll try the other alternatives such as clearing the profile.

Comment: @Erik What do you mean by reducing the time until network timeout?
I wouldn't think there is a problem with the saving as in other PCs the project loads normal.
The connection is good (93Mbps download & upload, 32 ping).

Comment: By the way my attempts have all been with an Ethernet cable plugged in and currently I've got version 3.28.8 of QGIS in the problematic PC

Comment: "If I load the same project in another workstation with the same specs, except this one has another SSD, of 2 TB; then, in this one the project loads in 30s." As you pointed out maybe is a problem of virtual memory (pagination) since the project size is 70 Gb and doesn't fit in RAM, how much free space do you have in that 256 Gb SSD? And how are the settings for virtual memory in that Win11 machine?

Comment: Also consider running QGIS over Linux (any distro but Ubuntu, MX Linux with KDE desktop is greatly recommended) at least as an experiment, and you will see a considerable increase in performance.

Comment: @PepeNO The 226GB SSD has 50GB of free space, so that shouldn't be a problem. Furthermore, there is a consumption of 10 GB of RAM from a total of 16, not a problem too. 
I clarify that the problem is both loading from Drive and loading locally, so the virtual memory is not an issue. 
If I don't find a solution, I decided that I would reinstall W11 completely rather than switching to Linux.

Comment: Probably a malware or virus on W11, besides over time and program installations invariably becomes slow, a fresh install will do the trick but not for long.

Comment: @PepeNO If you mean uninstalling and installing QGIS again, I already did it 3 times. If you mean reinstalling WIndows, I'm considering it but as the last option. Now I'll try to change the profile.

Comment: I tried with a new profile and now the project loads in 10-20s.
I'll have to find out if the following missing plugins are necessary:
qgis2web
quick_map_services
profiletool
ParallelLineConstruction
qgiscloud
IPyConsole
PluginLoadTimes
qchainage
db_manager

Comment: sorry, the dbmanager is also installed in the new profile and the plugin "LoadTimes" was installed by me to debug, so it's not necessary for the user.

Comment: Hi everyone, just wanted to give you an update that the problem has been solved. After weeks of debugging, the cause of the slow load time was the plugin "qgiscloud". I disabled that plugin. Now the project gets loaded after 10-20s both from Drive and locally.